# Python multiprocessing more infinite loops at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-multiprocessing

**EDIT: I SOLVED IT! DON'T MAKE THE SAME MISTAKE AS ME**

replace this line:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=check(mval,mname))
```

with:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=check, args=(mval,mname))
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

.

.

.

I am making a robot with Raspberry Pi and some microswitches and I want to check the microswitches if they are triggered so I'm using the multiprocessing module, the process class to be exact with a few infinite while loops and the problem is that one starts and waits until it is triggered and ends and starts the next one instead of all of them starting and running independently. Here is my code so far.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

def check(mval, mname):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        check = GPIO.input(mval)
        if check == False:  
            print("triggered "  + mname)
            with open("tmp.txt", "w"):
                pass
            f = open("tmp.txt", "w")
            f.write(mname)
            f.close()
            break

def startcheck(mval, mname):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=check(mval,mname))
    p.start()
    p.join()


startcheck(32, "m1")
startcheck(7, "m2")
startcheck(12, "m3")
startcheck(36, "m4")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join() function causes each loop to terminate before the next one starts.  From the standard library docs:

"join([timeout]) 
If the optional argument timeout is None (the default), the method blocks until the process whose join() method is called terminates. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds.

A process can be joined many times.

A process cannot join itself because this would cause a deadlock. It is an error to attempt to join a process before it has been started."

Solution: remove the join() line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i removed the join() line but the issue persists. It still executes one at a time instead of all at the same time.

Comment: Does the PI actually support multiple processes?  Generally I thought that a "Process" in Python represents a thread executing on another core of a multicore CPU.  I might be wrong about that.  See the docs for multiprocessing.cpu_count().  The returned value from that function may provide a clue.

Comment: It returns 4, I have looked more into the Pi supporting multiple processes and found a sample code which runs perfectly fine [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=129358) so the problem must be elsewhere.